# Laravel BelongsToMany attach() not working

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to store members shoping day when each member will registered. but here `attach()` method  not working.It say `Integrity constraint violation: 1452`. Bui i defined `BelongToMany` relationship .
Here is my `Member` model :

```
public function dayShop(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Days::class, 'member_shops','member_id','day_name');
 }
```

And Here is My Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $member = new Member();
        $member->name=$request->name;
        $member->balance=$request->balance;
        $member->email=$request->email;
        $member->password=Hash::make($request->password);
        $member->role=$request->role;
        $member->save();
        $member->dayShop()->attach('1', ['day_name' => 'Something']);
        return back();
    }
```

`member_shops` Table :

```
 Schema::create('member_shops', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('member_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('member_id')->references('id')
            ->on('members')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('day_name')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('day_name')->references('name')
            ->on('days')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

And Error is:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`meal`.`member_shops`, CONSTRAINT `member_shops_day_name_foreign`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`day_name`) REFERENCES `days` (`name`) ON DELETE CASCADE
>   ON UPDATE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `member_shops` (`day_name`,
>   `member_id`) values (Something, 18))

Comment: Can you paste the migration files for the respective models as well?

Comment: `Schema::create('member_shops', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('member_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('member_id')->references('id')
                ->on('members')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->string('day_name')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('day_name')->references('name')
                ->on('days')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });`

Comment: Why do you have onUpdate('cascade')? In the schema? Is it updating another table when a new row is added?

Comment: i removed `onUpdate('cascade')` but same error

Comment: Did you re run the migrations after removing it?

Comment: you have problem with this `$table->foreign('day_name')->references('name')
            ->on('days')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');` remove this relation and if you want to add relation with day then reference it with day id

Comment: @rkj working...

Comment: glad it works for you

Comment: i forgot  that this relation will work only with primary key

Comment: Is day_name 'Something' exists in days table?